# Existe diferença em "ligar-se" ao container via docker attach ou docker exec?

Tags: docker

Minha dúvida é: existe diferença em "ligar-se" a um container utilizando a instrução `docker attach` e `docker exec -it container /bin/bash`?

Meu container foi criado desta forma:
`docker run -it -p 80:80 --name dev debian:stretch /bin/bash`

Cheguei a ler alguns posts quanto ao assunto, pelo que pude entender, `docker attach` é uma instrução utilizada para conectar ao container sem abrir um novo processo, ou seja, ele conecta ao Shell instanciado no momento da criação do container.

Caso eu execute: `docker exec -it container /bin/bash` estarei criando um novo processo.

**Como docker é um mundo razoavelmente novo para mim, não tenho certeza se este entendimento está correto.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `docker exec` é utilizado para enviar um comando para o container em questão, quando você faz `docker exec -it container /bin/bash`é enviada uma instrução para o container abrir um processo do bash e mantê-lo aberto até que feche. Olhando a [documentação](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#extended-description) é possível entender melhor essa questão.

Enquanto que o `docker attach` anexa o stdio do container ao seu terminal, é como se você usasse um ssh, isso está escrito na [documentação](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/#extended-description).

Em todo caso, se você quer visualizar os logs de um container use o [`docker logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/). Se você quiser rodar um comando no container, crie um [dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage), pois a ideia do container é ser reutilizável e se você fizer o comando com o container rodando, quando reiniciá-lo (possivelmente acontecerá), precisará fazer o comando de novo.